# Buscar nome região/cidade php

Tags: php, javascript, api

Estou a usar a Weather API da Yahoo. A questão é que quero que o tempo seja apresentado para a localização do utilizador.

Tendo em conta que estou a usar o seguinte:

```
$BASE_URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
$yql_query = 'select item from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="Lisbon, pt")';

$yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query) . "&format=json&u=c";
```

Funciona tudo muito bem, mas neste caso ele devolve o tempo para Lisbon, pt (A localização está definida na query).

Eu quero a partir de php ir buscar a localização do utilizador, mas se for pelo IP, ele devolve a localização do serviço de internet, o que significa que não é onde o utilizador está de verdade. Há outra maneira de contronar isto? É que já consegui ir buscar por javascript, mas não posso usar uma variável javascript em PHP.

Comment: tens de ir buscar o ip do local onde estas , com o ip sabes a localização geografica.

Comment: https://www.mylesgray.com/software/use-geolocation-get-user-location-weather-ip-address/

Comment: @user2964140, o ip onde estou não dá. Como referi, o ip é do meu fornecedor de internet, que fica numa localização diferente. Mas obrigado na mesma

Comment: só assim é que consegues...podes ter um array de locais e forçar...a selecção

Answer (score 1):

Não existe uma forma automática para descobrir a localização precisa do usuário, a não ser perguntando para ele ;)

É possível obter a localização aproximada do usuário através do endereço IP dele. Você pode utilizar um serviço como http://ipinfodb.com/my_ip_location.php para obter os dados sobre a localização através do IP.

Comment: sim, mas por javascript conseguimos pedir a localização do browser, pedindo ao utilizador. Isso não é possível em php?

Comment: Não. O PHP roda no servidor. O JavaScript roda no navegador. A funcionalidade de localização é do navegador, logo apenas com JavaScript é possível obter isso. O que pode ser feito, é obter via JS e passar para o PHP (por exemplo, via Ajax).

Comment: isso é uma boa ideia. Obrigado